# How to skip csv files who are empty?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I know there are so many threads about this issue but NOTHING works for me.. 
I have a folder with a million of csv files and I want to read them with pandas :

```
for i in result:
    df = pd.read_csv("bigfolder/"+i, parse_dates=True, delim_whitespace=True, header=0)
    if len(df) > 2:
            df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
            df['just_dates'] = df['time'].dt.date
```

I think there are empty files because I always get the error: "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file".
Is there an easy method to skip this files. I tried a lot but nothing works.. I think it seems not to be that much difficult but I can't find a solution since two days. Please help!

Comment: one way would be filtering a file based on the file size.

Comment: why dont you use try except for this :-|

Comment: @NagaKiran I tried it but it doesn't work.. can you show me a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception handling comes handy.

```
for i in result:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv("bigfolder/"+i, parse_dates=True, delim_whitespace=True, header=0)
    except Exception as e:
        #print('File {0}: {1}'.format(i. str(e)))
        pass
```

Comment: Can I do something that just skip the files when I am in case "except"? When I just use "return" I become the error : "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function"

Comment: @Dennis you want to stop the loop? just use "break"

Comment: no not to stop. Just do nothing and go on .. quasi without the print

Comment: @Dennis use "pass", refer to my edit above

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.errors import EmptyDataError

try:
    df=pd.read_csv("bigfolder/"+i, parse_dates=True, delim_whitespace=True, header=0)
    print(df)
except EmptyDataError:
    print('empty dataframe')
```